# $resource delete function not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, cookies, angular-resource

I have built a simple application in Angular consuming a simple API I created myself using Laravel. The application is hosted [here](http://angulair.rohanchhabra.in). The API is hosted [here](http://angulairapi.rohanchhabra.in). Now I can log in to the application at which point the API returns a simple `auth_token` which is sent as the URL parameter in every subsequent request that is sent to the server.

There is only one user in the system:

```
Email: admin@admin.com
Password: admin12345
```

You can log into the application using these credentials at which point the application will set a cookie using the `$cookieStore` service and will use the token in this cookie for every subsequent request. After using the application, a user can log out from the application, where a `DELETE` request is sent to the server and on the success method, the cookie is deleted from the browser.

Unfortunately there is some issue with the code I suppose. The `DELETE` request is working as expected and it deletes the `auth_token` on the server and returns `200 OK`. But the success method is not called. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. It might be just a syntax problem.

**app.js**

```
function AppCtrl ($scope, $cookieStore, $location, Auth) {
  $scope.setActive = function (type) {
    $scope.destinationsActive = '';
    $scope.flightsActive = '';
    $scope.reservationsActive = '';

    $scope[type + 'Active'] = 'active';
  };

  $scope.authenticate = function (credentials) {
    Auth.save(credentials, function(data){
      $cookieStore.put('auth_token', data.auth_token);
      $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
      $location.path('destinations');
      $scope.message = null;
    }, function(data){
      $scope.message = "Email/Password combination incorrect!";
    });
  };

  $scope.logout = function () {
    //var auth_token = $cookieStore.get('auth_token');
    Auth.delete({
      'auth_token': $cookieStore.get('auth_token')
    }, function(data){
      $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
      $cookieStore.remove('auth_token');
    });

  };

  if($cookieStore.get('auth_token')){
    $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
  }else{
    $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
  }

}
```

The logout function is called when the log out button is pressed. What am I doing wrong here?

**Note: The application is not working on Chrome for some reason (Use Firefox). If you can shed some light on that, it would be very helpful.**

Both the repositories are public if you wish to have a look:

AngulAir Application: http://gitlab.learningtechasia.com:8901/rohan0793/angulair.git

AngulAirAPI: http://gitlab.learningtechasia.com:8901/rohan0793/angulairapi.git

Comment: There are 2 files which are not loading in chrome.Giving 404 error.
http://angulair.rohanchhabra.in/js/controllers/login.js http://angulair.rohanchhabra.in/controller.js 
That may causing a problem..

Comment: I know. That is what I don't understand. CORS is enabled on my server. The site works on Firefox and fetches all files.

Comment: same issue in Mozilla, i saw the same error in network tab of developer tool

Comment: I just digged into your project & found that..controllers/login.js & controller.js is missing from your git repo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution

```
$scope.logout = function () {
    //var auth_token = $cookieStore.get('auth_token');
    Auth.delete(
    {'auth_token': $cookieStore.get('auth_token')}, // parameters
    {},//postData, which you don't need for this
    function(data){
      $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
      $cookieStore.remove('auth_token');
    },
    // error callback
    function (httpResponse) {
       // do what you want for error handling here
    }
  );  
  };
```

**Note:->**  (Below points solved the problem)

1. Only the 2nd option(postdata) in $resource.delete API was missing. We should give it as a blank {} if it is not required for API.
2. And delete method should return 204 Status Code in order to execute success callback.

Comment: When I press the log out button, the success method is not called for some reason. I tried inserting a `alert('hello')` in there, and it did not fire.

Comment: After fiddling around for a while, I realized that the response code generated from the server was 200, but usually a 204 is sent after a delete request is generated. This is why the success method was not called and it was causing issues deleting the auth_token from the browser cookie.

Comment: You can edit the answer with the syntax problem and add the response code problem and I will accept it. Please keep the response code edit in  bold so that anyone else developing an API which is to be consumed would understand if he stumbles here.

Comment: Yes, because I just corrected the response code in my API which is why it is working.

Comment: Yes, I did. I am using your code in my application. You corrected my syntax issues. Thank you for that. It still wasn't working because the response code did not fire the success method. But when I fixed the response code, everything fell in place. That is why I am asking you to add that point in your answer so that anyone else having a similar problem will understand that the delete request needs a 204 to fire the success method.

Comment: I edited my answer. If you felt something wrong you can correct it at any time. Thanks bro.

Comment: Did you get any clue for that CORS issue?

Comment: I am not sure. The application is still not working in Chrome for some reason.

Comment: I will let you know, if i get something in it..Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67676/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-rohan).